# React: Route is not working inside of loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Why this is not working ?

```
<Provider store={ store }>
   <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
          {routes && routes.map(
              (config, i) => <PrivateRoute key={ `route-render-${ i }` } config={ config } />
          )}
       </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

But If I changed the `PrivateRoute` to `Route` the content of component will work as expeceted.

Here's my `PrivateRoute.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class PrivateRoute extends Component {
    render() {
        const { config: { access, roles, ...rest } } = this.props

        return (
            <Route { ...rest } />
        )
    }
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Here's the `routes` looks like

```
import * as shared from '../modules/shared/pages'

export const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        roles: [],
        access: [],
        exact: true,
        name: 'Login',
        component: shared.Login
    },
    {
        name: 'PageNotFound',
        component: shared.PageNotFound
    }
]
```

Comment: What does the `routes` array look like?

Comment: Hi @Leandro, I updated my question

Comment: `Login` is working and `PageNotFound` is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrivateRoute needs to have `path`, `exact`, `component`, `render` props, all the normal route props.

So you can do is pass those props along with additions configs like

```
<PrivateRoute path={config.path} component={config.component} config={config} />
```